# Android Studio : Error injecting while Appengine backend generation

Tags: android, google-app-engine, maven, android-studio

I've installed maven 3.1.1 and using app-engine-sdk 1.8.9

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Track-AppEngine 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Track-AppEngine ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ Track-AppEngine ---
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /Users/satvik/Project/Track-AppEngine/target/Track-        AppEngine-1.0/WEB-INF/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.0:endpoints_get_discovery_doc (default) @ Track-        AppEngine ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: com.google.appengine.endpoints.EndpointsGetDiscoveryDoc
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/sonatype/aether/RepositorySystem;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806) and goes on and on.

Finally I get build failed and a bunch of [ERROR] tags.
```

Every time I generate Appengine Backend I get this error. Please help.
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the issue is because of maven 3.1.X with appengine-maven-plugin 1.8.0

Check this

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/FgZrGAJr0T8/VaEXYgPUX7cJ

and reported issue for the same is here

https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/detail?id=31

If you need to use the plug-in with Maven 3.1.0 then you can use the latest `1.8.3` version of plugin instead of 1.8.0 .

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I am using Maven 3.2.3 and appengine-maven-plugin 1.9.17 and still facing the issue, pl help.